# Connecting to a RabbitMQ Deployment hosted on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to connect to a RabbitMQ Deployment cluster created by Google Compute Engine. 
After the successful deploy I'm able to get into the web management interface through the ssh tunneling command provided.

Now I'm not able to connect my client to the RabbitMQ instance. Tried using both with VM Ephemeral IP and `rabbitmq-all-nodes-XXXXX` load balancer IP.

We use Node `amqplib` and we connect using the admin user account on the canonical URI:

```
amqp://user:pass@host:5672/vhost
```

Nothing more than ECONNREFUSED is returned to us so it's pretty hard to find out the problem

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your rabbitmq deployment setup to accept external connections?

From what I remember it will only accept connections from localhost by default, you need to change the listening IP to 0.0.0.0 or similar (+restart) to be able to accept external connections.

Comment: Not sure, the request to the machine running RabbitMQ must be internal since it is forwarded by the Load Balancer that Google automatically creates when you deploy a Rabbit cluster.

Comment: When i say internal, i mean from the same host as rabbitmq is running on.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I typed enter and submitted an incomplete comment. 

On the VM I've now added a rule to accept TCP:5672 connections but nothing seems to change. Anyway it could be the right path to tackle, I'll play a lil bit and let you know.

Comment: Anyway looking at this url https://developers.google.com/cloud/rabbitmq/click-to-deploy in the "Load balancing the cluster" paragraph it doesn't mention any network configuration it makes sense since it's the load balancer that has forwarding rules to Rabbit's VM so it's the one which should have access to the VMs without additional setup

Comment: Ok problem fixed, it was about adding a network rule allowing ```TCP``` connections on port ```5672```. The connection string must not end with a ```/``` if you're not connecting to a specific vhost.

Comment: Hi Ian, the connection suddendly was truncated on the RabbiMQ cluster side. Everything looks up & running and I can access the admin interface but my clients cant connect anymore to it. We receive a "connection Timeout". Do you know what could be the reason?